# Maneuvering Speed Discrepancy

Tags: aerodynamics, aerobatics

In this page from the limitations section of the Extra Flugzeugbau 330SC, it states

[image]

I’m curious as to the discrepancy between maneuvering speeds Va between operation in the Normal Category and the different, and higher maneuvering speed Va when operated in the acrobatic category.

Maneuvering speed, as I understood it, what is the speed at which the airplane could be subject to a full deflection control input where, speeds below that would result in exceeding the critical angle of attack and stalling the airplane, and speeds above that, such an input could cause structural damage to the airframe, or sub components of that.

Now granted an Extra 330SC is built like a brick sh*thouse, allowing for a maximum load factor of +/- 10 Gs and some maneuvers can be entered at Vne without any problems.  That being said, I’m surprised to see the Va higher for acro flying that for normal category flight.  Anybody know what’s going on here? Is this a regulatory function, as opposed to a structural limitation?

Comment: It may be related to G limits between the 2 categories.  The NO seems to be based on the structural limits of the aircraft itself.  In other words, at a slower airspeed, an AoA increase must be greater to get the same Gs.

Comment: Every time I think I might be on to an answer it hits a dead end. This must be due to regulatory requirements regarding engineering safety factors for the two categories. I can't think of any physics reason why the structure would support more lift when operating in one category than the other. Is there a section of the POH that lists the operational assumptions for each category? (fuel load, accessories, and such) Is the fuel in the wings or fuselage? For small normal cat aircraft max wing lift is almost always used for Va, only in large planes where other loads like rudder may be limiting.